# Count number of rows with conditions met in multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I can use

```
=COUNTIFS(range1, criteria1, range2, criteria2…) + COUNTIFS(...) etc
```

[Count number of rows with conditions met in two columns](https://superuser.com/questions/166097/count-number-of-rows-with-conditions-met-in-two-columns?rq=1)

My data is such that the above will require needing approximately 150+ instances of countifs just for one cell. And I need to do this for 10K or so cells.
So wondering if there is another function/way to do this in a more efficient manner? **Example** of data as follows;

```
1    2    10    6    
2    3    9    4                   
3    4    8    5               
7    6    7    2
4    5    1    6                  
2    1    6    7
5    6    2    8               
2    5    3    10
6    7    2    10
```

And need to count how many times number 2 & 6 occur on the same row.

EDIT: I also need to do this with any number combination. ie 2&6, 1&6, 5&10 etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with a serial no from 1 to n.

Then use a nested if:

```
SUM(IF(SERIAL_NO = SERIAL NO 
  IF( IF COLUMN1 =2 AND COLUMN 3 = 6,10))) AS 26
```

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with SERIAL_NO? Are you able to elaborate at all? Thanks